# Firefox Select dropdown is not inheriting page font

Tags: css, firefox

A problem I'm encountering on my web pages is that on Firefox (and Firefox only), the options inside `<select>` tags are not affected by `font-family: inherit`.  The `<option>`s should inherit `<body>`'s specified font-family their parent's specified font family.

Instead, they use the fonts specified in the user's Firefox profile. So, if the user's Firefox settings have the default font type set to "Serif", Dropdowns look gross. The select element in itself inherits the page font properly but the options in the dropdown don't, as you can see here:

[image]

They should have the same font as the first option in the select.

Is there any way to make them? I've tried to specify a CSS rule to make them inherit the font forcefully but it doesn't do anything:

```
option {
    font-family: inherit;
}
```

Forcing a font works but that's not necessarily what I want.

Is there a way to do this without editing the DOM or without using JS, or is this just impossible with Firefox?

Comment: Disabling `-moz-appearance` (or `appearance` for newer versions) should work, without forcing.

Comment: To me in this case "Instead, they use the fonts specified in the user's Firefox profile." would be the proper functionality - user is in charge due to things we know little about - for example vision challenges etc.  OR just put/force what you want (sansserif) in your CSS since that is what it is for

Comment: example `font-family: sans-serif;`

Comment: Encountering the same issue. Does anybody have a proper solution?

Comment: @SharathDaniel I wasn't able to find one and had no choice but to set `font-family: sans-serif`. Using JS I was able to detect that the options' computed font was indeed my page's font, so it's literally a bug on Firefox's end for not taking the font into account. When I manually edit the font family to be something specific like Comic Sans, it works, so maybe using JS to set the dropdown's font after the page has finished loading is the only way. i haven't tried it personally.

Comment: see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1536148

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me.

```
select, option {
  font: -moz-pull-down-menu;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Options, except the first one, do not show the assigned font family.